# How to properly position and activate a hyperlink in PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to write a code which adds hyperlinks to existing PDF document.
I've tried to do that by following PDF 32000 specification but seems that I'm missing something.

PDF viewer shows my link annotations and changes the mouse pointer to "finger" when hovering over them, but **no URLs are shown, and clicking on them doesn't do anything**.

PDF contents are shown below.

Page:

```
/Type/Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox[0 0 594.75 841.5]
/Contents 7 0 R
/Resources 8 0 R
/Annots [5 0 R 6 0 R] % added by me
```

First annotation (for "Google", #5):

```
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Link
/Rect [60.0 779.25 150.0 767.25]
/BS
<<
    /W 2 % should be 0, set to 2 to be able to see the annotation's position
>>
/F 4
/A
<<
    /Type /Action
    /Subtype /URI
    /URI (https://google.com)
>>
```

Second annotation (for "DuckDuckGo", #6):

```
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Link
/Rect [342.0 694.5 432.0 682.5]
/BS
<<
    /W 2 % should be 0, set to 2 to be able to see the annotation's position
>>
/F 4
/A
<<
    /Type /Action
    /Subtype /URI
    /URI (https://duckduckgo.com)
>>
```

Content stream:

```
1 0 0 -1 36.0 841.5 cm
-100 Tz
q
/Font3 -9.0 Tf
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg
24.0 62.25 90.0 12.0 re W n
BT
1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm
24.75 69.75 Td
(Google) Tj
ET
Q
q
/Font3 -9.0 Tf
0.0 0.0 0.0 rg
306.0 147.0 90.0 12.0 re W n
BT
1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm
306.75 154.5 Td
(DuckDuckGo) Tj
ET
Q
```

This code produces the following result:

[image: rendered pdf]

[Generated PDF file is available here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9ude5yypvelgnq/links.pdf?dl=0)

I took a look on the code the Microsoft Word produces for the links, and it looks pretty much the same (except minification and structural parent; this code works, but mine is not):

```
/Subtype/Link/Rect[ 69.75 697.51 113.16 720] /BS
<<
    /W 0
>>
/F 4/A
<<
    /Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://google.com/) 
>>
/StructParent 0
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action dictionary looks like this:

```
<<
    /Type /Action
    /Subtype /URI
    /URI (https://google.com)
>>
```

If you lookup ISO 32000-1 section 12.6.2 *Action Dictionaries*, though, you'll see that the type of action is not the value of **Subtype** but instead of **S**:

> **S**
>   name
>   *(Required)* The type of action that this dictionary describes; see Table 194 for specific values.

*(ISO 32000-1 Table 193 – Entries common to all action dictionaries)*

Thus, in your **Action** dictionary (***not*** in the surrounding **Annot** dictionary, though!) replace `/Subtype` by `/S`:

```
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Link                    %<------------- not here
/Rect [342.0 694.5 432.0 682.5]
/BS
<<
    /W 2 % should be 0, set to 2 to be able to see the annotation's position
>>
/F 4
/A
<<
    /Type /Action
    /S /URI                       %<------------- but here
    /URI (https://duckduckgo.com)
>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've seen `/Subtype /URI` in several Q&A here on SO and didn't notice dedicated section in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the page content and process all operators that affect text position in order to compute the exact position of Google and DuckDuckGo. Then place the link annotations at the computed positions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how, exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "how exactly"? It's specified in ISO 32000. Thus: what have you tried, what failed to work?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I did something wrong in terms of position calculation, but there was a bug in my code. Link position is calculated by taking a clipping path from the content (`24.0 62.25 90.0 12.0 re W n`) and applying a coordinate transformation (using the current transformation matrix `1 0 0 -1 36.0 841.5 cm` defined at the beginning of the content).

Comment: Again, sorry for the confusion, I've removed this part from the question. The main issue with links - they don't work at all, but seem to be valid according to ISO 32000.